# Avoid errors during Archiving in IOS without code modification

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I was using the Product >> Archive in XCode to create the build with "Generic IOS Device".
[image]
[image]

I am receiving the following error 
[image]

These codes run perfectly in the simulators (iPad retina , iPad etc..). How should i create the archive without modifying the codes, because i have a lot of similar errors, probably due to change in version.

Comment: Have you imported QuartzCore?

Comment: You are using forward declaration (f.e @class CALayer), import QuartzCore instead. P.s. I guess it's not just can't archive but also can't be built